# how to use regex under find command

Tags: regex, linux, find

I need to list all filenames which is having alien.digits 
digits can be anytime from 1 to many 
but it should not match if its the mixture of any other thing like alien.htm, alien.1php, alien.1234.pj.123, alien.123.12, alien.12.12p.234htm

I wrote:
find home/jassi/ -name "alien.[0-9]*"
But it is not working and its matching everything.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
find home/jassi/ -regex ".*/alien\.[0-9]+"
```

With `-name` option you don't specify a *regular expression* but a *glob pattern*.

Be aware that find expects that the whole path is matched by the regular expression.

Comment: Yes true I did that exactly and now it's working fine 
I wrote: find /home/jassi -type f -regex ".*/alien.[0-9]*" although + would also work instead of * :) Thanks bmk

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `find home/jassi/ -name "alien\.[0-9]+$"`
It will match all files that have `alien.` and end with at least one digit but nothing else than digits. The `$` character means *end of string*.

Comment: this kind of regex will not work and it will throw and error .
error is Illegal variable name.
You cannot use + or $ and * means everything. Perl regex style will not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

The `*` modifier means 0 or more of the previous match, and `.` means any character, which means it's matching `alien`.

Try this instead:

```
alien\.[0-9]+$
```

The `+` modifier means 1 or more of the previous match, and the `.` has been escaped to a literal character, and the `$` on the end means "end of string".

You can also add a `^` to the start of the regex if you want to make sure that only files that exactly match your regex. The `^` character means "start of string", so `^alien\.[0-9]+$` will match `alien.1234`, but it won't match `not_an_alien.1234`.

Comment: If it would be Perl, I would say you are right but its Linux box and it will not work for sure. I found something regex inside a find command we need to use that. I am trying now.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:
find home/jassi/ type -f -regex ".*/alien.[0-9]+"

I had to provide type -f to check if it's a file , else it would show the directory also of the same name.

Thanks bmk. I just figured out and at the same time you responded exactly the same thing. Great!